# How to pass data to another page after ajax GET

Tags: ajax

I want to pass into another page x.php after clicking the button, and pass dataBtls to x.php, where all data getting by Ajax 'GET' will be operated.
I used window.location.href, but it didn't work.

document.querySelectorAll(".btnModifier").forEach(function(element){

```
  element.addEventListener("click", function(evt){

    let id = evt.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
    
    // call ajax
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let method = "GET";
    let url = BaseURL+"index.php?requete=modifierBouteilleCellier";
    //let url = BaseURL+"index.php?requete=formModificationBtl";
    let asynchronous = true;
    // receiving response from url
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
       
        window.location.href = BaseURL+"index.php?requete=formModificationBtl";
        
        //converting JSON back to array
        let dataBtls = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(dataBtls);

        //looping through the data
        for (let i = 0; i < dataBtls.length; i++){
```

Comment: I don't see you have pass `dataBtls` in url .Instead do like this : `window.location.href = BaseURL+"index.php?requete=formModificationBtl&dataBtls="+dataBtls` .Make sure to put this line after `let dataBtls = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`